# Desktop web browser how accurate is navigator.geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, gps, browser

I was  wondering for my website, how accurate is the GeoLocation attribute of the navigator object in desktop web browsers?  I guess on a mobile web browser this simply activates a GPS device so therefore is based on GPS signal at that time.  However what about on a desktop?  Does it have some means of determining its location and to what accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

[According to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/):

Under the [interface section](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#geolocation_interface):

> The Geolocation object is used by scripts to programmatically determine the location information associated with the hosting device. **The location information is acquired by applying a *user-agent specific* algorithm**, creating a Position object, and populating that object with appropriate data accordingly.

Under the [requirements section](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#requirements_section)

> 6.2.8 The Geolocation API **must be agnostic to the underlying sources of location information**.

TL;DR: Depends on the browser's implementation. This could mean that it could use anything available on the device. *It may* even be possible to have "Mobile Provider" and "GPS" on a PC, since there are devices like [Nokia Booklet 3G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_Booklet_3G) that has GPS and can be inserted a SIM.

Comment: thanks but on my laptop it produces I believe an accuracy of 65m where I am and I was wondering how it obtains the gps coords simply from the wifi network it appears.  I certainly have nothing else connected to my computer.